# Twillio Connection desclined

Tags: php, twilio-twiml

i am trying to call through twillio using my browser, i have got access token but when i try to call using javascript following error occurs

> code: 31002, connection: {…}, message: "Connection Declined", twilioError: Error

PHP Code:

```
$token = new AccessToken(
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            3600,
            'voice'
        );


// Allow outgoing voice calls to Twilio phone numbers

$voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant();
$voiceGrant->setOutgoingApplicationSid('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$token->addGrant($voiceGrant);

//$token->allowClientOutgoing('+12707196558');

// Generate the token and return it as JSON
return response()->json(['token'=>$token->toJWT()]);
```

javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get a Twilio Client token from the server
    $.getJSON('{{route('get_token')}}', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var token = data.token;
        // Request permission to use the microphone
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
            .then(function (stream) {
                // var connection = Twilio.Device.connect();
                // Create a Twilio.Device instance with the token and stream
         
                var device = new Twilio.Device(token, {
                    codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
                    fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                    enableRingingState: true,
                    debug: true
                });

                console.log(device);

                setTimeout(async function () {
                    const call = device.connect({To: '+923056477442'});
                }, 5000);

              
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Could not get user media:', error);
            });
    });
});
```

i have setup my twiml url with https